# Cannot replace string text in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to replace a test in `pom.xml` using a groovy script. These are my two approaches. The text should be replaced is `{env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}`

**Approach one**

```
File mainPomXml = new File(rootDir,'/pom.xml')
mainPomXml.text.replace('{env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}','${env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}');
```

**Approach two**

```
def mainPomXml = new File(rootDir,'/pom.xml')
def mainPom = mainPomXml.text.replace('{env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}','${env.AM_$environment.toUpperCase()_SERVER_CREDS_USR}');
mainPomXml.write(mainPom);
```

But none of these approaches work. That means both executes but the test is not get replaced. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Approach 1 can not work - it is basically a no-op.  Read it as `mainPomXml.getText().replace...`; the second approach should work. Please be more specific **what** does not work.

Comment: It won't replace the text. It's same as it is even after executing the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the mainPom part as below.

```
def mainPomXml = new File(rootDir, '/pom.xml')
def mainPom = mainPomXml.text.replace('AM_SERVER_CREDS_USR', '${env.AM_'+ env.toUpperCase() +'_SERVER_CREDS_USR}')
mainPomXml.write(mainPom)
```